# How can I properly escape JavaScript in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, escaping, quotes

This might be something I can't do but...

```
parent.document.getElementById('<?php echo $_GET['song']; ?>')
  .innerHTML = '<img src="heart.png" onmouseover="heartOver('');" >';
```

The `onmouseover="heartOver('');` portion breaks my JavaScript. Is there a way to escape the quotes so I can do this?

Comment: It would be clearer if you used the HTML this produced - the PHP doesn't have anything to do with it in this case.

Comment: @Greg: i just pared it down to the bit he's actually concerned with. Hope that helps...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Escape nested quotes with a backslash: `\'`

Also, **never** echo user data without validating or sanitizing it:

```
$song = $_GET['song'];

// Validate HTML id (http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-html40/types.html#type-name)
if(!preg_match('/^[a-z][-a-z0-9_:\.]*$/', $song) {
    // Display error because $song is invalid
}
```

OR

```
// Sanitize
$song = preg_replace('/(^[^a-z]*|[^-a-z0-9_:\.])/', '', $song);
```

Answer (score 5):

It's all just a matter of escaping the quotes properly.

```
parent.document.getElementById('<?php echo $_GET['song']; ?>').innerHTML =
    '<a href="heart.php?action=unlove&song=<?php echo $song; ?>" target="hiddenframe">'
    + '<img src="images/heart.png" alt="Love!" onmouseover="heartOver(\'\');" width="16" height="16" border="0"></a>';
```

Also you're missing and end quote for the alt attribute.

Comment: Nice catch about the missing end quote.

Answer (score 1):

Your issue is with escaping quotes. You can escape either a single or double quote by replacing ' or " with \' or '".

So your code would be:

`parent.document.getElementById('<?php echo $_GET['song']; ?>').innerHTML = '<a href="heart.php?action=unlove&song=<?php echo $song; ?>" target="hiddenframe"><img src="images/heart.png" alt="Love! onmouseover="heartOver(\'\');" width="16" height="16" border="0"></a>';`